# Time zone inconsistency between as.Posixct and fastPOSIXct

Tags: r, timezone

I have two questions regarding the following voodoo:

```
time.string = '2012-08-31 21:30:54'
> as.POSIXct(time.string)
[1] "2012-08-31 21:30:54 IDT"
> fastPOSIXct(time.string)
[1] "2012-09-01 00:30:54 IDT"
```

1) How does R know my time.zone?

2) Why does fastPOSIXct know my time zone but shows me the corresponding GMT time?

How do correct the fastPOSIXct?

Comment: `fastPOSIXct` *is* GMT-specific. The [function's](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/fasttime/fastPOSIXct.html) title is `Fast version of as.POSIXct.character for GMT fixed format`. If you don't want GMT you shouldn't use it

Comment: R knows your timezone, because it calls `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` and so it knows were you are located. Of course you can set the LC_TIME by hand.